# using a square tin in a small oven

Tags: baking, equipment

I have a family size convection microwave oven instead of a full size oven.  I make fruit cakes and have to change the tin for next year's competition.  I've always used a round tin and now I have to use a square tin.  How do I stop it from burning at the corners before the middle is cooked?  I set it at 130 dgeress Centigrade and bake for 3-4 hours

Comment: 3-4 hours? Or 3/4 hour?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I personally love the hard edges of the brownie.
But to your question: 
    There are a few things that you can try to keep the edges from burning.

- Use a lighter ( both color and heaviness ) pan, as this does affect the heating rate as well as the distribution of the heat throughout the pan.
- Try keeping your ingredients at a relative room temperature so there isn't a large transition from cold to hot in this oven ( the same reason you thaw some things before cooking ).
- Try changing the temperature and cooking time. The recipes I usually stick with for brownies are cooking for about 30m at about 350 degrees F (175 c).

One last thing that might work that I have had to do with pie is wrapping foil around the edges until the last 10-15minutes of cooking.